# Connected to the Internet, but can't ssh or ping

Tags: wireless, ssh

I'm having a problem with my Raspberry Pi where I can't ssh into or even ping it, yet I'm using it on my TV, and it's clearly connected to the network/Internet.

I've used the attached keyboard to run several [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) commands, [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), and `apt-get update`, and they all work fine, but I can't connect to it remotely using the IP address, and it won't respond to pings. I've just freshly installed [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software), and so far all I've done is set up Wi-Fi, which is clearly working.

Comment: Does your computer that you're sshing from have a firewall ? Have you double checked the IP address with `/sbin/ifconfig` just in case it's not the correct one ?

Comment: No, it actually worked fine right before i rebooted for the first time after I setup the wifi (I ssh-ed to make sure it worked, then rebooted, at which point it stopped working). I double checked the IP with "ifconfig wlan0" and found it to be the same as it has been.

Comment: update: I restarted it for the 20th time and it is now working...

Comment: plz paste your ifconfig

Comment: I had a similar experience with a SD card corrupted by an inefficient power supply.

Comment: This might be a power saving issue with your wifi dongle. Try to maintain it busy with eg `ping google.com` on the Pi and try ssh'ing at the same time.

Comment: @MNoit, this was it for me, thanks! Now to work out how to disable this 'feature'.

Comment: I don't see how it can be a power/dongle issue if the pi does connect to internet.  I can ping google fine, but sometimes can't ping the pi from within the network, despite fixed ip etc..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens a lot with one of my Raspberry Pis. I have a script which checks for an Internet connection and runs `ifup wlan0` when a connection is not present. Some of the things you could try:

- Rebooting the Raspberry Pi
- Checking that you have a valid IP address using `ifconfig`
- Ensuring that you have power-saving features disabled on the dongle by adding `wireless-power off` to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file
- Run `ifup --force wlan0`

Here's a script which runs every five minutes from cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to check the network connection

#Check network connection
if /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep -q "inet addr:" ; then
    #Connection is good; do nothing
    echo "$(date "+%D [%H:%M:%S]") Connection is up"
else
    echo "$(date "+%D [%H:%M:%S]") Network connection down. Attempting to reconnect..."
    sudo /sbin/ifup --force wlan0
fi
```

If that is a wireless card power management issue, you can also have a look at *[WLAN disappears after some time](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51543&p=397663)*.

Many wireless network cards don't support `wireless-power off` option in `/etc/network/interfaces`. To disable power management with a [8192CU](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277) module loaded, you can create a file `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf` with the following contents.

```
# Disable power management
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

Comment: The internet connection is working and has a valid IP address, though I think your suggestion of adding "wireless-power off" has worked. If it doesn't fail in the next few days I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Did the fix work? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @exantas: Can you share that script? I think I will need it too.

Comment: @zengr: edited my answer

Comment: ah, the problem I am having is, I see `inet addr:` in ifconfig and I have a valid IP address but I am not able to ping/wget etc.

Comment: can you ssh into it?

Comment: no, I cannot. I have plugged in a monitor and using it for now.

Comment: What dongle are you using?

Comment: Ralink RT5370. It connects to the internet, works if I don't do anything. But if I do `apt-get install nmap` (or anything else) it hangs at random say at 48%. And after that, ping, ssh etc do not work.

Comment: Did you follow any of the suggestions in my answer e.g. turning power saving off?

Comment: yup, tried that. I don't think power is an issue because it stops working within seconds if I do some data intensive activity like pull data over the internet.

Comment: I think you've found the cause of your problem but unfortunately I have no idea why that would happen. Could be anything, even a power supply issue...

Comment: posted a new question here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/wifi-drops-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: I was unable to download anything and it kept failing, now seems the only reason was because of the power management issue. Thanks.

Comment: This happend to my Raspberry PI 3 Model B on Raspbian Jessie Lite (version February 2016). Thank you for this answer, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I have found myself in this issue before. Sometimes my router would pick up the wrong IP address. To fix the issue I used [`nmap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) to find my Raspberry Pi. I think that the command was `nmap 192.168.1.0/24`.

That should be able to find the IP address and help you to ssh and ping. If you are connected by a monitor then run [`ifconfig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) inside the terminal application.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problems. With an Ethernet connection I could remote desktop from my PC into the Raspberry Pi, but with Wi-Fi the connection failed; I couldn't even ping the Raspberry Pi.

It turned out to be a router problem. I created a new rule for routing port 3389 (used by [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol)) to the IP address of the Raspberry Pi (I also setup the router to assign the same IP address to the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the Raspberry Pi Wi-Fi). This resolved the problem. Ping still fails sometimes; I suspect that is more related to the power management solution mentioned above.

I found the instructions for my NetGear router setup in *[Port Forwarding the Netgear WGT624v3 Router for Remote Desktop](https://portforward.com/netgear/wgt624/304.htm)*.

Answer (score 0):

try using *raspi-config* and enable ssh from interface option.

Comment: Will enabling SSH in the `raspi-config` fix the issue with ping? OP wrote: "*I can't [ ] even ping it.*"